# hibernate.cfg.xml not found in spring mv3 application

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am using spring mvc3 and hibernate3. In my application i have a requirement to use a servlet. 
In that servelet I have to call my DAO Layer. but when I am using following code in my servlet.

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
public class HibernateUtil {
    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    static {
        try {
            sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure()
                    .buildSessionFactory();
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

I am getting error org.hibernate.HibernateException: hibernate.cfg.xml not found.

Currently my xml file is in WEB-INF folder along with other configuration file.

All solutions are saying I need to keep it in src folder so automatically it will be fetched at runtime. but I am using spring mvc here.
So i am little bit confuse please help me how to solve it.

all other places where I am using controller its working fine.

[image]

I am using following entry in carpool-servlet.xml

following is my carpool-hibernate.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" 
        xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
            ">

    <context:property-placeholder location="/WEB-INF/dbproperties.properties" />

    <!-- Enable annotation style of managing transactions -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />   

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean"
                 p:dataSource-ref="dataSource"
                 p:configLocation="${hibernate.config}"
                 p:packagesToScan="store.custom.controllers">

                <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>common.domain.Ride</value>
            <value>common.businessclass.PostAdRR</value>
        </list>
    </property>
                 </bean>

    <!-- Declare a datasource that has pooling capabilities-->   
    <bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
                destroy-method="close"
                p:driverClass="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
                p:jdbcUrl="${jdbc.url}"
                p:user="${jdbc.username}"
                p:password="${jdbc.password}"
                p:acquireIncrement="5"
                p:idleConnectionTestPeriod="60"
                p:maxPoolSize="100"
                p:maxStatements="50"
                p:minPoolSize="10" />

    <!-- Declare a transaction manager-->
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager" 
                p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory" />

</beans>
```

following is my hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC

        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"

        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">


<hibernate-configuration>

  <session-factory>
    <!-- We're using MySQL database so the dialect needs to MySQL as well-->
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</property>
    <!-- Enable this to see the SQL statements in the logs-->
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <!-- This will drop our existing database and re-create a new one.
            Existing data will be deleted! -->
<!-- <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>-->
  </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

**now how can I set my hibernate config.xml**
Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where is hibernate.config being set

```
p:configLocation="${hibernate.config}"
```

If you are using maven, you can move this file to src/main/resources then do classpath:hibernate.config.xml, otherwise if you're not, move it within classpath under WEB-INF/classes as duffymo stated.

Comment: Actually the problem is I want to user my dao layer in my servlet, and if we use spring mvc the dao layer meand daoservice will be accessible by default, as this service is autowired, but if i want to user the same servie in my servet, that is not controller then i am not able to configure. Please help

Comment: So you want to be able to access the service outside of the MVC controller?  If that's the case I'd make a separate controller on a different URL (say /api in this case or something) which exposes the service allowing access to the DAO. This controller could be much more concise in it's operation, and act as more of a web service than a view controller which I'm assuming your original controller is doing.  If you want to go another route, like having a Jersey servlet or something, you'd have to do another package scan when the context is initialized.

Comment: Thanks dardo, i am trying the same, still not luck, now I am trying if   any how i can use my servlet as a controller, if i will put my servlet in scan package and put all annotation, I am trying but its not working. no luck :(

Comment: I am trying your suggestion  like jersey servlet, but not clear how to implement it, means we need to duplicate all configuration again.

Comment: What type of servlet are you tying to the scan package.  A spring servlet such as DispatcherServlet is going to naturally look for an application context, if you're just using a JavaEE servlet, there will be no Spring container created and package scan will not work.

Comment: If you're implementing a jersey servlet, you need to have it talk to spring through a context listener.  Here's a blog post that should get you started. http://javaswamy.blogspot.com/2010/01/making-jersey-work-with-spring.html

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend moving .cfg.xml into your CLASSPATH.  That means putting it in WEB-INF/classes, not WEB-INF.